# Image display in the Browser issue using php

Tags: php

I have 2 scripts - imageDisplay.php

```
<?php
$image = 'images/Banner7.jpg';
// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData;

// Echo out a sample image
echo $src;
?>
```

And index.html script - which I am using to display an image from a folder

```
<img src="showImage.php?images=Banner7.jpg" />
```

However, I am only seeing the image icon as shown below

[image]

But on checking FireFox - Network Response, I can see the full image as it ought to be and right clicking on the image icon above, view image I can still see the proper image as shown below:

[image]

I have several of them and would like to display them as base64 and later print them on pdf.

**My problem**:

look at the code above and help me get the image displayed correctly in the browser.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning an `<img>` tag, you are basically echo'ing an `<img>` tag into an `<img>` tag's `src` attribute which effectively looks like this:

`<img src="<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64">">`

In your `showImage` script, there's no reason to base64 encode anything, that's only need when you are using a text-based transport like HTML. Since you are transporting over HTTP which supports binary, you can instead just send the file. There's a couple of ways, but the easiest is:

```php
echo file_get_contents($image);
exit;
```

Another option that is a little more performant for larger files is:

```php
readfile($image);
exit;
```

If you want to get a little fancier, you can also output the MIME for the file:

```php
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($image));
readfile($image);
exit;
```

**edit**

I should also point out that passing filenames as parameters without sanitization and validation is a big security problem that can lead to [path traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal) problems. At a minimum, I'd call `basename()` on the supplied parameter, but you should probably look into your specific setup to see what could or couldn't go wrong.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas, thank you for getting back quickly than expected. The idea of using base64_encode is because I want to print these images on pdf which does not accept other forms.

Comment: advise me on how to get around this issue. Thanks

Comment: @kibikawanjala, you are going to need to post more about what you are trying to do. I do [know a good amount about PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a231316%20%5bpdf%5d) so I can promise you that regular binary images in a PDF work fine, but it is possible that your PDF creation library has a nuance that needs to be worked around. Specifically, I'm thinking that it isn't able to resolve relative vs absolute images.

Comment: no doubt, perused thro and u seem to possess impeccable experience in pdf creation process. Spot on! - it is about resolving relative vs absolute images - using docRaptor;[link](https://help.docraptor.com/en/articles/1986775-development-testing-localhost-servers) and will eventually use Princexml to convert html containing mathjax markups and images to pdf. I am open to using any other library to render html to pdf. I hope you can see what i'm trying to achieve. Thank u.

Comment: @kibikawanjala, you probably want to look into the [`baseurl` option](https://help.docraptor.com/en/articles/1067834-image-css-or-javascript-file-not-loading)

Comment: I have looked at baseurl option and hit a dead end. Is it possible to convert mathjax + images to pdf using iTextSharp since you seem to have a solid understanding of the tool? Thank you.